# Simple Spring Boot Application - HttpServletResponse needed

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-boot

I want the simplest spring boot application like...

```
@Path("/")
@Component
public class RestResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I want to build a REST application and I need the `HttpServletResponse` because I want to check some conditions and then do a redirect for example.

```
@Context
private HttpServletResponse servletResponse;

...

if (...)
    servletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    servletResponse.sendRedirect(...);
else
    servletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.XYZ);
    servletResponse.sendRedirect(...);
```

What is the best way to get the `HttpServletResponse` in a Spring Boot application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need `HttpServletResponse` the following will do.

```
@RequestMapping("/urlmapping") 
public String method(HttpServletResponse response){

  .....

  if (...)
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    response.sendRedirect(...);
  else
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.XYZ);
    response.sendRedirect(...);

  .....

}
```

In the above example the `HttpServletResponse` object will be injected.

In the example I used `@RequestMapping` it should work for `@Path` also.

Comment: @Path is a JAX-RS annotation, so RequestMapping is the necessary annotation for a Spring application.